# SQL Server Authentication in ASP.NET Login

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication, webforms

I am trying to find a way to login in my web application (WEBFORMS) using the login tool that comes with the SQL Authentication.

However I am trying to find a way for each time a user logins, it uses that credential to execute queries.
For instance you have Jacob and Sam using the same application at the same time.
Jacob signs in using his credentials, Username: Jacob; Password: Password1
Sam signs in using his credentials, Username: Sam; Password: Password2

When the application execute an insert statement on behalf of Jacob, it uses Jacob's credentials in MSSQL to execute the command. So when going through the SQL Log (.ldf) file it states that Jacob committed that that transaction so for each user separately however Windows Authentication is not an option.

Comment: So...prompt the user for their credentials and use the values when you make your connection to the SQL Server...

Comment: every time they execute a command i should prompt them their sql credentials?

Comment: We have no idea what your app does or how many commands it might issue.  If it's more than one, it sounds like you need a way to store credentials.  Or have a session that uses the same credentials as SQL and pass the user's current session credentials.

Comment: it is an enterprise application build with different components
Imagine: Subjects, Transport, Mortgage registration
with an average of 15 users.

whenever a user updates i am using web.config to connect to sql. when i want to check which user changed what in the sql log it gives the general user which is stated in the web.config

Answer (score 0):

The fact that user A or B logs on has ZERO to do with the web sites ability and connection to the database. Two very different concepts.

Since the user is logged on then any insert to the database can include say their logon ID in that table. But as a general rule, the connection to the database is the same in both cases.

So the web site is what will "restrict" what projects, or things or whatever a given user will see and ONLY see. This is done at the application level.

So, if a user is to create a booking, or whatever?

Well, based on their logon, you have their email, but also the sql authentiation logon provider also has a PK row id for each user.

So, when you add a new project, you just make sure you set who the record belongs to. say like this:

```
     dim lngUSERid as integer
     lngUSERID = Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey

    rstProject = MyrstEdit("Select * from dbo_projectHeader where id = 0", strCon, rUpdate)

    With rstProject.Rows.Add

        .Item("ContactGeneralID") = rstContact("ContactGeneralID")
        .Item("ContactNameID") = lngUSERID
        .Item("CreatedBy") = ngUSERID
        .Item("Created") = Now()
        .Item("ProjectName") = strProjectName

        .Item("QuoteNum") = myQuoteNum
        .Item("QuoteDate") = Date.Today
        .Item("VOID") = 0       ' False
  End With
```

So, when each user logs on and say they add some "user" project, then you code just has to save their PK logon ID.

So, at that point in time?

when they logon to the site, then say code to display their projects? It will look like this:

```
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("dbo.GetProjects", GetCon)
    cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@LogonID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey

        Dim rstGridData As DataTable
        rstGridData = MyrstP(cmdSQL)

        ListView1.DataSource = rstGridData
        ListView1.DataBind()
```

So, now the user sees a list  of ONLY their projects.

So, it not clear what kind of logon provider you are using. But, given this is a web forms, then you have a HIGH chance you using the built in .net provider that is based on sql tables.

So, once that user is logged on?
Then any query or pull from a table has to include their "log on ID" as part of that query pull.

This is NOT really any different then say if you wrote a desktop program for a company that uses sql server or whatever. it will be YOUR code that restricts who and what users can and will see - not the database system.

Now in a lot of cases, if your desktop program enables one to look up some company information, then all employees can probably do that.

But, if each employee is ONLY supposed to see their OWN information? Then you will have to include some user identification in each record you save.

For the most part, you only need this at the top most level.
I mean if you create a new project?

Then those projects are all the user can choose to work on. But, say you click on  project to show project details? Well, that project details does NOT need to save user logon things, since they can never get to the project details unless they first choose the project to work on from a list of THEIR projects.

So be this web based, or even just desktop based? In both cases, the restricting of records to each user is managed by the application, and NOT the database system.

however, one will most certainly use the security system and setup fo the web site. And pages that let a user view projects will not be available until such time a legal logon is had, else such pages will not be displayed.

Thus, such pages are going to use IIS security, but the restricting of the data they see will in most cases be based on their logonID.

So, you like in any typical logon system will have some security groups that let people do certain things. So, for example, only SOME users might be granted rights to delete a project. But those security groups are done though the web site part, and not the database part.

And note how I did not save the user FirstName, Email and other information into that table. I ONLY needed their logon "id", and additional information such as FirstName, or address or whatever? That's in the user logon table.

So, that user will ONLY ever see their own data.